# complete webscraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

need some help in using beautifulsoup library for webscraping.

I need to extract the text from the webpage [http://thehill.com/…/365407-sean-diddy-combs-wants-to-buy-c…](http://thehill.com/%E2%80%A6/365407-sean-diddy-combs-wants-to-buy-c%E2%80%A6)

my goal is to extract the text exactly as in the webpage for which I am extracting all the "p" tags and its text, but inside "p" tags there are "a" tags which has also some text.

so my questions:

1. how to convert the unicoded ("") into normal strings as the text in the webpage? because when I only extract "p" tags, the beautifulsoup library converts the text into unicoded and even the special characters are unicoded, so I want to convert the extracted unicoded text into normal text. How can I do that?
2. How to extract the text inside "p" tags which has "a" tags in it. I mean I would like to exract the complete text inside the "p" tags including the text inside nested tags.

I have tried with the following code:

```
html = requests.get("http://thehill.com/…/365407-sean-diddy-combs-wants-to-buy-c…").content
news_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
a_text = news_soup.find_all('p')

y = a_text[1].find_all('a').string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension to find all links with the paragraph tags and use `encode("ascii", 'ignore')` to decode the unicode:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = soup(str(urllib.urlopen('http://thehill.com/blogs/blog-briefing-room/365407-sean-diddy-combs-wants-to-buy-carolina-panthers-and-sign-kaepernick').read()), 'lxml')
all_text = [i.text.encode("ascii", 'ignore') for i in s.find_all('p')]
all_paragraphs = filter(None, [[b.text.encode("ascii", 'ignore') for b in i.find_all('a')] for i in s.find_all('p')])
print(all_text)
print(all_paragraphs)
```

Output:

```
['Hip hop mogul Sean Diddy Combs said Sunday night hes interested in buying the Carolina Panthers and signing quarterback Colin Kaepernick, who has been unemployed this season after kneeling during the national anthem in 2016.', 'Panthers owner Jerry Richardson announced Sunday he would be selling the team after the 2017 season, just hours after Sports Illustrated published accusations of sexual misconduct from former employees. Richardson also allegedly used a racial slur about a team scout.', 'Diddy took to Twitter soon after the Panthers announced the upcoming sale, declaring his desire to own a team and increase diversity among NFL ownership.', 'I would like to buy the @Panthers. Spread the word. Retweet!', 'There are no majority African American NFL owners. Lets make history.', '', 'Kaepernick respondedSundaymorning, saying I want in on the ownership group!', 'I want in on the ownership group! Lets make it happen!, 'Other athletes, including NBA starStephen Curryandformer NFL playerGreg Jennings,responded to Combs saying they were interested in part-owning the team.', "Former league MVP Cam Newton is the team's current quarterback.", 'Kaepernick has been a free agent since the end of the 2016 season, when he made headlinesfor kneeling during the national anthem before games to protest issues of racial inequality.', 'President TrumpDonald John TrumpHouse Democrat slams Donald Trump Jr. for serious case of amnesia after testimony Skier Lindsey Vonn: I dont want to represent Trump at Olympics Poll: 4 in 10 Republicans think senior Trump advisers had improper dealings with Russia MORE hascriticized Kaepernick directly, saying the NFL should have suspended him for the demonstration. He has since taken aim at other players who have knelt or sat during the anthem during the 2017 season.', '- This story was updated at 11:03 A.M. EST.', 'View the discussion thread.', 'The Hill 1625 K Street, NW Suite 900 Washington DC 20006 | 202-628-8500 tel | 202-628-8503 fax', 'The contents of this site are 2017 Capitol Hill Publishing Corp., a subsidiary of News Communications, Inc.']
[['Sports Illustrated'], ['@Panthers'], ['Stephen Curry', 'former NFL player'], ['President Trump', 'Donald John Trump', 'House Democrat slams Donald Trump Jr. for serious case of amnesia after testimony', 'Skier Lindsey Vonn: I dont want to represent Trump at Olympics', 'Poll: 4 in 10 Republicans think senior Trump advisers had improper dealings with Russia', 'MORE', 'criticized Kaepernick directly', 'knelt or sat'], ['View the discussion thread.']]
```